# Writing to a blob In Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, console-application, azure-blob-storage

I have the following console app pointing to .Net Core 2.1 which does the simple thing of reading and writing from and to the blob.
I have hidden the account key with * here.But the connection is happening properly.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
string connectionString = $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=r53eripcjroswtest;AccountKey=***;";

                // Setup the connection to the storage accounts
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

                // Connect to the blob storage
                CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                // Connect to the blob container
                CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("igb-test");             
               

                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Test.txt");
                string contents = blob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;

                //blob.UploadTextAsync("This is coming from the Program");
           
            
        }
    }
}
```

I have run the above code and am able to read the content of the file in "contents" variable.
But when i am trying to write to the file (after uncommenting the ---blob.UploadTextAsync("This is coming from the Program")--line and commenting the read line) , nothing is being written to the file.

**Note**: The text file is empty in the beginning. First i tried to write to the file through my console program,nothing happened then opened the file and wrote it manually and was able to read its contents.

When i tried to run the same code through an azure function and published it to azure portal, it is able to read and write from/to the file.

My question is we cannot use a .exe(console application) to write to a blob in azure? and only through function apps it can be done?
Can anybody please guide me on where I am going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `UploadTextAsync` is an async method, you will have to wait for it to finish (like what you're doing in download). Please try the following code:

```
blob.UploadTextAsync("This is coming from the Program").Result;
```

or you could simply use synchronous version of the method:

```
blob.UploadText("This is coming from the Program");
```

Comment: This works! But i have a question as to what is meant by waiting for it to finish?
I am allowing to the code to run fully till the end.
How to know that async method has ended?The reason why i am asking this is after running the code till the end , i waited like for 5 mins and still nothing was written to the blob.

Comment: When you execute a method asynchronously, the execution happens over a background thread and you will need to wait for the background thread to finish the operation. That's what I mean by `waiting for it to finish`. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are doing it using Async. If you do it with Async then you need to do like this.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WriteToBlob
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var writeTask = WriteToBlobAsync("hello world 123");
            writeTask.Wait();
        }

        public static async Task WriteToBlobAsync(string text) {

            string connectionString = "*";

            // Setup the connection to the storage accounts
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

            // Connect to the blob storage
            CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Connect to the blob container
            CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("test");


            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.txt");
            string contents = blob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(contents);
            await blob.UploadTextAsync(text);


        }
    }
}
```